# reg to extract content from parenthese

Tags: python, regex

I have this `string = "abc('abt')"`, and I would like to just extract the value.

I tried: `string = string.strip("abc('/)")` i am using python. if the result is 't', but I would like 'abt'. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex that will find everything inside single quotes inside parentheses. It searches for an opening parenthesis followed by a single quote, then collects everything leading up to another single quote and closing parenthesis:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "abc('abt')"
>>> regex = re.compile("\('(.*)'\)")
>>> m = re.search(regex, s)
>>> m.group(1)
'abt'
```

Answer (score 1):

`.strip()` takes a *set* of characters to remove. You are removing all the `a`, `b`, `c`, `(`, `'`, `/` and `)` characters form the start and end. Only `t` is then left.

You could split on `'` instead:

```
string.split("'")[1]
```

or you could explicitly remove the exact characters from the start and end with slicing:

```
string[5:-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^=]*=\sabc\(['"]?(\w+)['"]\)$
```

This regex will catch what you want into first group. I'm not sure how to extract it's value in python, let me google a bit :)

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"^[^=]*=\s\"abc\(['""]?(\w+)['""]\)\"$")
input = "string = \"abc('abt')\""
matches = regex.match(input)
your_val = matches.group(1)
```

Note that this regex will work only for strings with "value" like "abc''"

Sorry, I've got no Python at hand, not tested, but I think you've got the idea.